# Como instalar el modulo QT Designer en Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, qt, pyqt5

He instalado **PyQt5** en **Linux** pero no se como se instala o se ejecuta el modulo **QT Designer**, agradecería si alguien me puede ayudar.

Comment: Ejecuta los siguiente: `sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools`

Comment: Muchas gracias  por tu respuesta.

Comment: Para la siguiente puedes hacer la busqueda de un paquete por ejemplo: `sudo apt-cache search qtdesigner`

Comment: Excelente información! Muchas gracias nuevamente por tu apoyo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
```

Comment: especifica mejor tu respuesta para que la comunidad entienda mejor

Comment: Buenas por favor mejora tu respuesta, ve [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que la comunidad te entienda mejor y sea realmente aceptada.